# Adjust UITextfield width

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

I have a UITextField inside of a table cell and am trying to use interface builder to extend the width.  However no matter how much I drag it, it remains at 97.  Am I not allowed to extend it for some reason?  Thanks

EDIT:  Attempting to edit the text or increasing the font truncates the text..the UITextField will not change dimensions to accommodate it - it remains at 97 x 30.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interface builder is tricky when it comes to some thing.

Your best bet is to modify the text field's frame in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` in tableview's datasource method. That should fix this kind of problems.